# I get an error when I install the gem i18n-0.7.0.beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to run a test, so I run rake:

```
Could not find i18n-0.7.0.beta1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then I run bundle install and get this:

```
Using rake 10.4.0

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-
0.7.0.beta1.gem)
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.7.0.beta1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0.beta1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I do `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0.beta1'` and get this:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'i18n' (= 0.7.0.beta1), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

What do I do now?

Comment: Do you develop on windows or *nix?

Comment: Are you using a mac? If so have you tried `rvm osx-ssl-certs update`?